# How can I add a menu of local Trac projects to templates/site.html?

Tags: trac

I have multiple Trac projects with different environments on the same server.  I would like to have a list of links to all projects at the top of each project page so I can quickly switch between them with out having to go up to the top level list at /projects/.

The ideal solution would:

1. not require loading all the Trac environments on every page load.
2. update automatically when a new project is added.
3. only require editing the config and/or templates or add a plugin.
4. work for Trac 0.11.

Comment: Did you found a solution, was either answer suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NavAddPluggin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/NavAddPlugin) allows the main trac navigation bar to be customized. You could add menu options for each trac of your projects. To add a new menu item the following is added to the `trac.ini file`.

```
[navadd]
add_items = project1
project1.target = mainnav
project1.title = Project One
project1.url = http://webserver/trac_project_1
```

To sort the order edit the `mainnav` option in the `trac.ini`

`mainnav = project1,wiki,timeline,roadmap,browser,tickets,newticket,search`

Comment: Although this would work it is not the solution I'm after.  I would have to edit the menu on each Trac every time I added a project.  I'm looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: @jcoffland- It's not as hard as you'd think.  You can have a separate .ini file that inlcudes all the menu options and use `[inherit]` to include it in all of your Trac instances.  That way, you update one file and all Trac instances will get the changes automatically.

Comment: Yes like @bta said just `[inherit]` from a single .ini you could even write a small bash script to do and update it when a new project is created but I can't see you're created multiple projects daily for this to be an issue.. your mainnav would run off the screen anyway if that was the case.

Comment: @sudo_O Ok, I didn't know about [inherit].  I was hoping for an automatic solution.  This still requires some manual editing each time a project is added but it does answer the question as written.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of how to add a meny using `site.html`, here is a very basic top header to get you started - paste into the `site.html` placeholder:

```
<!--! A top header -->
<py:match path="body" once="True">
<body py:attrs="select('@*')">
    <div id="top">
        <a py:if="req.href() != '/one'" href="/one">one</a>
        <a py:if="req.href() != '/two'" href="/two">two</a>
        <a py:if="req.href() != '/three'" href="/three">three</a>
    </div>
    ${select('*|comment()|text()')}
</body>
</py:match>
```

The example uses very simple logic and just hides the current project . You may want to do it differently, typically using highlighting or similar.

See [Trac Layout Recipe](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CookBook/TracLayoutRecipe) for an advanced example. This is the layout in use at edgewall.org to switch between the various projects (Trac, Genshi, Babel, Bitten).

Answer (score 0):

The method described by sudo_o is probably your best bet.  It will give you something that is very well integrated into the Trac interface.

However, I wanted to mention a quick-n-dirty alternative that you may find useful.  You can configure the logo in the upper-left corner of every Trac page to link to a specific page when clicked.  Many Trac installations use this to link back to the start page.  The link is configurable, however, and you can make it point to your project listing page.  In your `trac.ini` file:

```
[header_logo]
src = site/your_logo.png
link = /url/to/projects/page
alt = Click to load projects listing
```

This method gives you easy access to your projects listing, and doesn't require adding any extra entries to your Trac menus.  When you add or remove projects, you don't have to modify every `trac.ini` file to update the links.  The downsides are that it takes an extra click to get to another project and that some users might not find this method as intuitive (setting the `alt` property helps with this a little).

Comment: This solution doesn't quite do it for me.  I want a menu of projects directly on the Trac site.